# Git: Clear local and remote master and start over but keep master in other branch

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to clear master and start over but keep master on other branch to save history and work or it must be other project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible.  First create a new branch for historical purposes.

```
git checkout --detach master
git branch old_master
```

Next delete `master`.  (That's why we checked it out `--detached`; we couldn't delete it while having it "properly" checked out.)

```
git branch -D master
```

Now we're ready to start a new history

```
git checkout --orphan master
```

Now your next commit (assuming no intervening `checkout`s) will recreate `master` with a brand new history.

Just keep in mind that your working tree and index still have the content from `old_master`; all of that will show up as staged/uncommitted work.  You can of course wipe the index and work tree clean if you want a truly fresh start.

After you do all of this, your next push of `master` will have to be a force push.  Any time you do a force push, that means you need to coordinate with anyone else who shares the repo / branch.  See `recovering from upstream rebase` in the `git rebase` docs, because that's essentially the situation this creates.